Made a Custom Post Type using ACF. Via the dashboard I cannot see the view button to see the post
I've made a Custom Post Type called Activity Providers.  In the Wordpress dashboard it shows up as it should in the menu, and I can create them, but the option to view each activity provider is not there.
I made another one quickly as a test and the option to view it IS visible.
I then compared both; they have all the same settings, just different names.  There is no cacheing and I tried to flush the rewrite rules.
Seems no matter what I do I cannot get the option to see the view button in the dashboard.
Anyone have any ideas?

I think you may check the Advanced Configuration of your CPT in ACF settings. There is an option to disable the View button in tab URLs called Publicly Queryable if it's disabled.
Publicly Queryable: disable


Publicly Queryable: enable



Thank you for your thought out and detailed response!

The setting was being over written by a third party plugin
